# [next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: next.js, next-auth

When I try to log in, I am getting this error. This will correctly sign someone up but it won't log them in properly and gives this error message. Can someone help me fix this?
The error:

```
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first_name') {
  message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first_name')",
  stack: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first_name')\\n" +
    '    at Object.session (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts:61:44)\\n' +
    '    at Object.session (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/session.js:38:52)\\n' +
    '    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:161:37)\\n' +
    '    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)\\n' +
    '    at async NextAuth.\_args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)\\n' +
    '    at async /Users/saadbaig/Desktop/test/sh02-main/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63251',
  name: 'TypeError'
}
```

Route.ts

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import  CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import prisma from "../../../../../prisma/client";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { User } from "@prisma/client";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider ({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: {label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Email"},
                password: {label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "Password"}
            },

            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) return null;

                const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({where: {email:  credentials.email}})

                if (!user) return null;

                const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.hashedPassword!);

                return passwordsMatch ? user : null;
            },
        }),
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        jwt: ({ token, user }) => ({
            ...token,
            user,
        }),
        async session({session, user}) {
            session.user.first_name = (user as User).first_name;
            return session;
        }
    },
    session: {
      strategy: 'jwt'
    }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export {handler as GET, handler as POST};
```

Can someone help, please?